# Word, Expand To Fill Table With Dots

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
                        Header1 Header2
I am a piece of text    Value1  Value2
```

I am trying to modify the table so that dots consume all the whitespace within the table, with the margins being at 0. The table is autosized to fit the window to expand/contract with different values. The expected results would look similar to the following:

```
                       Header1  Header2
I am a piece of text....Value1...Value2
```

The content in the table is constantly changing, thus I don't want to type in the dots but have the whitespace replaced with dots. Is this possible in MS Word?

Comment: You're on the wrong site (should be on SuperUser). But, look at tab leaders.

Comment: See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/fill-to-end-of-table-cell-could-be-multiple-as/3578285c-6a0d-49dd-bc1f-d05f6f29d05e